# Magento 2.4.3 issue in admin order totals

Tags: admin, orders, configurable-product, magento2.4.3.p1

I am using a module which calculates shipping rates with product weight. It sum up weight of each ordered product and returns total weight for each order.

It seems that if there is a configurable product inside an order exist, except simple one we have the following problem.

When there is a configurable product in order page inside admin we have blank the lower section with Order Totals:

[image]

And this error in exception:

```
report.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/public_html/vendor/mymodule/shippingtablerates/Model/Rate/ItemValidator.php on line 141 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/public_html/vendor/mymodule/shippingtablerates/Model/Rate/ItemValidator.php on line 141 at /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"}
```

The code responsible for this function is this:

```
/**
     * The method get value of weight data depends on attribute
     * from 'volumetric weight attribute'
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getItemWeight($item = null)
    {
        $calculatedWeight = [];
        $calculatedWeight['weight'] = $item ? $item->getWeight() : 0;
        $weightAttributeCodes = $this->configProvider->getSelectedWeightAttributeCode();

        if (!empty($weightAttributeCodes)) {
            if ($item->getProductType() == Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
                $productId = $item->getChildren()[0]->getProduct()->getId();
            } else {
                $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
            }

            $volumeWeight = $this->prepareVolumeWeight($productId, $weightAttributeCodes);
            $volumetricWeight = $this->configProvider->calculateVolumetricWeightWithShippingFactor($volumeWeight);
            $calculatedWeight['volumetric'] = $volumetricWeight;
        }

        return $calculatedWeight;
    }
```

In more details this line(141) throws the above mentioned error:

```
$productId = $item->getChildren()[0]->getProduct()->getId();
```

I am not an expert in coding and this is not my module...

If there is anybody who can help me to solve this it would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you get a solution?

Comment: It seems that after upgrading Magento 3rd party module this one is solved yes